# Extending Firebase notifications from Web app to Mobile app

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a website that uses notifications to users (on browsers) that go via Firebase, and this is working well.

I now have an Android App that someone developed for me, which basically houses the web site (via webView) along with some additional tools such as a QR reader. I myself am not an app developer but a web dev.

I would like to add the notifications to the App as well - he told me he has added what he needs to do on his side (in the app - via phonegap, I think), and that I need to add some code to the **web site**, so that that the notifications can work in the App as well. Does this make sense to anyone? 
Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I thought half the point of Firebase was that it's platform-wide.

Here is some config info that I have from the Firebase Console for the **web**:

```
// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    authDomain: "doi-18XXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://doi-18XXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "doi-18XXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "doi-18XXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "36XXXXXXX"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

And this is the `google-services.json` which I gave to the **app developer** (NOT on the website)

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "36XXXXXX",
    "firebase_url": "https://doi-18XXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "doi-18XXXXXX",
    "storage_bucket": "doi-18XXXXXX.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:36XXXXXXXXX:android:9e2XXXXXXX",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.doi.org"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "36XXXXXX-4XXXXXXXXXikpb8r3.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

And this is my **server-side code** (VBScript) that successfully sends notifications (currently only to web destinations):

```
posturl="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

body= "{ ""notification"": {"
body=body & """title"": """ & replace(messageTitle, """", "\""") & ""","
body=body & """body"": """ & replace(messageContent, """", "\""") & ""","
body=body & """icon"": ""/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png"","
body=body & """click_action"": """ & link & ""","
body=body & "},"
body=body & """to"" : """ & token & """}"

set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST",posturl,false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "key=AAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

xmlhttp.send body
result= xmlhttp.responseText
SendFirebaseMessage = result
Set xmlhttp = nothing
```

So... very confused - is he correct, that something needs to be added on my end somewhere?
Thanks!

Comment: You said your app developer uses phonegap, so it may be more a question about phonegap notifications api than firebase. You also have to know what notification API he exposed to you. (like this one for example : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md)

Comment: Here is an article about phonegap compatibility with FCM via the phonegap-push-plugin : https://blog.phonegap.com/announcing-phonegap-push-plugin-version-2-0-0-fd165349508f

Comment: @kneidels You do realize that after this bounty is rewarded, you won't be able to vote down or set bounties anymore, right? Perhaps you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @JL2210 - maybe i misunderstand: why will i not be downvote or post bounties anymore?

Comment: @Ricovitch - Thanks - checking if i can get the source code, then will know if its phone gap, or perhaps Cordova

Comment: @kneidels Your reputation will go below 75. "If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges."

Answer (score -1):

There are three parts to solving your scenario :

1. Server end code to POST notification to FCM.
2. FCM Project with all three apps created assuming you would also be needing IOS app.
3. Proper app-side device registration to FCM.

Workflow is simple, either you send notifications to a TOPIC, or a specific device using TOKEN.

> Using TOPIC solution, you don't need to worry about device TOKENS,
>   because if the device is registered to certain TOPIC on FCM, it will
>   receive the notification if you send for TOPIC.

Second solution, would be sending N number of POST requests to FCM, for N number of DEVICE TOKENS. 
You would also need to store DEVICE tokens at your server-end to make it work, suggestively hitting a server API when device gets registered on FCM in app code.

Reference link from official FCM documentation for explaination :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

What you need is to modify your following POST request to send to multiple devices or a certain topic or list of token:

```
posturl="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

body= "{ ""notification"": {"
body=body & """title"": """ & replace(messageTitle, """", "\""") & ""","
body=body & """body"": """ & replace(messageContent, """", "\""") & ""","
body=body & """icon"": ""/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png"","
body=body & """click_action"": """ & link & ""","
body=body & "},"
body=body & """to"" : """ & token & """}"
```

Below is the actual **groovy code** from my project used to build body for POST request to be sent to FCM :

```
private JsonObject buildNotificationMessage(NotificationCO notificationCO) {
        JsonObject messageJson = new JsonObject()
        JsonObject notificationJson = new JsonObject()
        notificationJson.addProperty("title", notificationCO.title)
        notificationJson.addProperty("body", notificationCO.body ?: '')
        messageJson.add("notification", notificationJson)

        if (notificationCO.token) {
            messageJson.addProperty("token", notificationCO.token)
        } else {
            messageJson.addProperty("topic", notificationCO.topic.toString())
        }

        if (notificationCO.data) {
            JsonObject dataJson = new JsonParser().parse(notificationCO.data)
            messageJson.add("data", dataJson)
        }

        JsonObject rootJson = new JsonObject()
        rootJson.add(firebaseCredentialsProviderService.messageKey, messageJson)
        return rootJson
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but i don't see how this relates to the question. My question related specifically to extending the Firebase integration to a mobile environment, where it exists already in web, and you pretty much summarized what my situation is but dod not refer to a solution. I dont even know what language your code is in..? still though, thanks for trying.

Comment: The code in groovy, although its is pretty much java if add semicolon at end of every syntax.
Also regarding your question I pretty much explained the whole process briefly, reference link from FCM : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message